# URLSession HTTP response handling

Tags: swift, xcode, urlsession

I have a file for handling http post requests to a NestJS api. My website works great with it, it accepts any response from the api. But in xcode, i have to hardcode the response. The website can accept a bool response, but xcode only accepts json as i know.

Can someone correct me, and tell me, if you can make xcode accept any response from the api. Thanks!

**HttpPOST.swift**

```
import Foundation
func apiCall(url: String, body: Dictionary<String, AnyHashable>, completion: @escaping (Response) -> Void){
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.71:3000/user/login")else{
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    // method, body, headers
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let body: [String: AnyHashable] = body
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .fragmentsAllowed)
    
    // make rqs
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ data, response, error in
        guard let data = data,error == nil else {
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            completion(response)
        }
        
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
    }
    
    task.resume()
}

struct Response: Codable {
    var usernameError: String?;
    var passwordError: String?;
    var logOk: Bool?;
    var token: String?;
}
```

**Response example**

```
Response(usernameError: Optional("enteruname"), passwordError: Optional("enterpasswd"), logOk: Optional(false), token: nil)
```

Comment: Can you show some examples of the responses?

Comment: You should show something what you deal with in your web in the comment code, or we won't know what kind of data your are dealing with.

Comment: Edited the response with an example

Comment: That's the output from printing out your `Response` object isn't it? That's not what I meant. **Can you show some of the raw data your server gives you, before you did any processing to it?** Especially those non-JSON ones that you mentioned.

Comment: What do you mean by « The website can accept a bool response» ? Are you saying that it just return «true» or «false» ?

Comment: Yeah, but i got it figured out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the return type generic to be able to return any `Decodable` type even a single `Bool` value.

This is a modern version of your code, it `throws` any possible error

```
func apiCall<T: Decodable>(urlString: String = "http://192.168.1.71:3000/user/login", body: [String:AnyHashable]) async throws -> T {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { throw URLError(.badURL) }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    // method, body, headers
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)
    
    // make rqs
    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
}
```

And use it

```
Task {
    do {
        let result : Response = try await apiCall(body: ["Foo":"Bar"])
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

To distinguish the `success` and `failure` cases declare `Response` as enum with associated values. It returns the token on success and the error messages on failure

```
enum Response: Decodable {
    case success(String), failure((String,String))
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case usernameError, passwordError, logOk, token}
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let ok = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .logOk)
        if ok {
            self = .success(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .token))
        } else {
            
            let usernameError = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .usernameError) ?? ""
            let passwordError = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .passwordError) ?? ""
            self = .failure((usernameError, passwordError))
        }
    }
}
```

and change the calling code to

```
Task {
    do {
        let result : Response = try await apiCall(body: ["Foo":"Bar"])
        switch result {
            case .success(let token): print(token)
            case .failure(let usernameError, let passwordError): print(usernameError, passwordError)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: The first one still requires a struct, is the second one fixes it?

Comment: `T : Decodable` accepts any type which conforms to `Decodable` including a single String, Bool or whatever. But the benefit of the enum is that it gets rid of all optionals.